# MATLAB: Manipulating Color of GUI Component using timer?

Tags: matlab, timer

How would I change color of a GUI component, specifically a static text box, after a certain timer period (say 3 seconds) using  a timer?

I tried

```
t = timer('TimerFcn', set(handles.tag,'BackgroundColor','red'),'StartDelay',3);
start(t);
```

But it returns this error:

> One or more outputs not assigned to set during callback.

I already know it means that set is not giving an input argument to the timer fcn. The problem is that a 7 segment display using this technique was already developed previously. But this is not working now.

Answer (score 1):

`'TimerFcn'` parameter should define a callback - [it has to be in one of the following forms](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html):

> String, function handle, or cell array defining the timer callback
>   function

You should specify your callback as a function handle, accepting [at least] two arguments (timer object / event):

> If you specify this property using a function handle, when MATLAB
>   executes the callback it passes the timer object and an event
>   structure to the callback function.

You can use anonymous function for that, and simply ignore both arguments:

```
handles.tag = uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'String', 'Some text');
t = timer('TimerFcn', @(~,~) set(handles.tag,'BackgroundColor','red'), 'StartDelay',3);
start(t);
```